# img on submit button - that is responsive

Tags: html, css, background

I want this [image]

on a submit button so I gave it as a background.
I'm doing the page responsive so I gave it the next css :

```
#button1{
   background: url('../images/button1.png') no-repeat;
   margin-top:-270px;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
   padding-right: 2%;
   width: 25%;
   position:relative;
   right:2.5%;
}
```

but when the page get smaller the image get cut.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Use "background-size"

Comment: thanks! that great! but know I need to use right minus something and it open a scroll-x and I can use hidden do you have any good solution for that?

Comment: To position a background, use `background-position`... Not sure what you mean with "it open a scroll-x"

Comment: thanks! you saved me!

Answer (score 0):

If you have or can get/crop out the arrow and the barcode separately as transparent PNGs or GIFs, you can do this:

```
#button1 {
   background: rgba(204,204,204,1);/* Old Browsers */
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(204,204,204,1) 0%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
   background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(204,204,204,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(102,102,102,1)));/* Chrome, Safari4+ */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(204,204,204,1) 0%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(204,204,204,1) 0%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(204,204,204,1) 0%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 100%); /* IE 10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(204,204,204,1) 0%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 100%);/* W3C */
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cccccc', endColorstr='#666666', GradientType=0 );/* IE6-9 */
   position: relative;
   border: 0;
   -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
   -moz-border-radius: 4px;
   border-radius: 4px;
}

#button1:after,
#button1:before {
   display: inline-block;
   content: url('img/button-barcode.png');
   margin: .5em;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

#button1:before {
   content: url('img/button-arrow.png');
}
```

The code employs pseudo elements `::before` and `::after` to put the arrow and the barcode into the `<button>` and **the button will be responsive** that way.

**P.S.** Works only on `<button>` tags, not on the button type of `<input>`!